# How to save / recover the state of the member variables of a fragment after orientation change

Tags: android, fragment, state

I noticed a strange behaviour on fragments.

As I understand, a fragment saves its views and variables by itself when a config change occurs. So when a config change occurs, you can get the same fragment you had, from the parent activity using FragmentManager this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(savedInstanceState == null) { //OK no problemo
        // Init fragments (first time)
        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity calling fgmt constructor");
        fgmt = new TestFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fgmt, "fgmt")
                .commit();
    } else {

        //Recuperar fragments
        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity before recover fragment");
        fgmt = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("fgmt");
        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity after recover fragment");
    }
```

But I noticed the following: when an orientation change occurs, the fragment constructor gets called automatically by the Activity class, i.e. on the Activity call to super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), this can be seen on Log output:

[image: log output]

But my fragment's cont variable value is allways 0 after orientation change.

So, I tried to use fragment onSaveInstanceState() to save the int value and recover it on onCreateView(), this obviously works. But, isn't the fragment manager able to save the fragment instance when an orientation change occurs?, 
Isn't supposed that when you recover a fragment from the fragment manager on Activity onCreate, this fragment is the same instance you had before the orientation change?

Thank you.

This is my code:

Main Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TestFragment fgmt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity before super");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity after super");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(savedInstanceState == null) { //OK no problemo
            // Init fragments (first time)
            Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity calling fgmt constructor");
            fgmt = new TestFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fgmt, "fgmt")
                    /*.addToBackStack("")*/
                    .commit();
        } else {

            //Recuperar fragments
            Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity before recover fragment");
            fgmt = (TestFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("fgmt");
            Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity after recover fragment");
        }

        Log.e("CHECK", "MainActivity onCreate done");
    }            
}
```

TestFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView tv;
    private int cont;
    private View root;

    public TestFragment() {
        Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /*
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            cont = savedInstanceState.getInt("cont");
            Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment recover cont = " + cont);
        }
        */


        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText("cont " + cont);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("cont " + cont);
                cont++;
            }
        });

        Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment onCreateView return");
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment onSaveInstanceState()");

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //outState.putInt("cont", cont);

        Log.e("CHECK", outState.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("CHECK", "TestFragment onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.leonides.fragmenttest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.leonides.fragmenttest.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see `setRetainInstance(true);` - Please read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: But I need to nest this fragment into another fragment, so I can't use setRetainStance(true);

Comment: Thanks  cricket_007, let me check if setRetainInstance(true); calls the constructor.

Comment: I think nesting fragments is a bad UI design choice, but you do what you want - it's your code